# NextJS and react-query

Tags: next.js, react-query

[image]

As you can see here, I used useQuery() but I only want it to fetch once. Not sure if it is NextJS problem or react-query problem.

Comment: please provide the code

Answer (score 1):

Without code is hard to evaluate, but this works fines for me in NextJS. Probably the problem is where you're calling `useQuery` hook

```js
function App (){
  const { loading, error, data: { listCourses: courses } = {} } = useQuery(
    listCourses(),
    {
      variables: { type: "online" },
    }
  );

  return (
    <Layout>
      {something}
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`react-query` does query retries out of the box. See the docs [here](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/query-retries). It is possible to disable it, passing `{ retry: false }` as options to `useQuery()` hook.